# How do I render objects with Altair in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, jupyter-lab, miniconda, altair

Lenovo Thinkpad, Windows 10.

I recently updated Conda which I haven't used in a while. I'm trying to use Altair and after updating via `conda update conda` and then looking at `conda list`, among some of my installed packages I see:

- jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
- jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
- jupyterlab                0.35.4           py37hf63ae98_0
- jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
- vega_datasets             0.7.0                      py_0   conda-forge

Other package versions you can see below as the output at cell 5. I've gone to the link in the docs and tried all the suggestions (except for pip install, which I'm trying to avoid for now) but nothing has rendered an image. Any suggestions as to why? Other than using pip, how can I resolve this? I'm about ready to just uninstall and reinstall miniconda entirely.

I've also tried `alt.renderers.enable('Jupyterlab')` in cell 4 and nothing changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in your error message goes [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#jupyterlab-vegalite-3-object) which says

> `<VegaLite 3 object>`
>
> This most likely means that you are using too old a version of JupyterLab. Altair 3.0 or later works best with JupyterLab version 1.0 or later

Update to JuptyerLab version 1.0 or later, and your chart should work. The reason is that older versions of JupyterLab do not include renderers for the Vega-Lite 3 charts produced by Altair 3.X.

Comment: If you run ``conda update jupyterlab`` it will update to the most recent version.

Comment: I did that and it did not update for me. EDIT: I had to remove jupyterlab and altair from my environment then reinstall them. Worked. Thanks.